# Error designing template XSLT to generate XML

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I need to generate this XML:

```
<bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagos" 
 xmlns:bdo_fosfec="http://asocajas.app.com/example" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <registro54 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro54">
   <registro82 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro82">
     <C512>39756656</C512>
     <C614>YAXMINNI</C614>
   </registro82>
 </registro54>
 <registro54 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro54">
   <registro82 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro82">
     <C512>79374740</C512>
     <C614>VICTOR</C614>
   </registro82>
 </registro54>
</bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement>
```

I built this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagos" xmlns:bdo_fosfec="http://asocajas.app.com/example" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="registro54"/>
   </bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement>
 </xsl:template>
 <!--TEMPLATE REGISTRO 54-->
 <xsl:template match="registro54">
   <registro54 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro54">
        <registro82 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro82">
          <C512><xsl:value-of select="C512"/></C512>
          <C614><xsl:value-of select="C614"/></C614>
        </registro82>
   </registro54>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, when I load my XSLT on C#, I get an error.

```
var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(myxslt);
```

> XSLT compile error. 'xsi' is an undeclared prefix. Line 11, position 19.

It's as if the "xsi" of the second template could not reach the definition of the first template. How can I fix my XSLT?

I have made some modifications to XSLT but not generate the result I want, what is the correct xslt design?

Comment: Try adding the `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` to the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: You need to declare any namespace you want to use in your XSL code.  Since your XSL never declares the namespace that goes with prefix `xsi`, the XSL processor cannot process this, so it throws the error.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - I think if you combined both of our comments it would make a decent answer. If you create the answer, I'll happily upvote it. :)

Comment: @DanielHaley rigth, this solve my bug, but the result xml is not as expected.. jumm... thnks anyway, i will try some things.

Comment: @Makitodev - If you end up needing more help, please create a new question.

Comment: @DanielHaley, thank you!  Done.  :)

Comment: @DanielHaley this is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045625/design-template-xslt-to-generate-xml thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces (and prefixes) in XSL can be tricky.

You need to declare any namespace you want to use in your XSL code.  Since your XSL declares the namespace that goes with prefix `xsi` in a limited fashion, the XSL processor cannot process this prefix when it appears outside the scope of the declaration, and so it throws the error.

Try adding `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` to the topmost `xsl:stylesheet` element in your XSL.  Breaking this down:

- The `xmlns` stands for "**XML n**ame**s**pace".
- The `xsi` is the prefix you want to use.  This could be anything -- it doesn't have to match the prefix in the input XML.
- The `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` part is the URI string identifying the namespace.  This part **must** match the namespace URI in the input XML, or your templates will fail to match.

I note that you *did* add the namespace declaration on a different element: `bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement`.  This is valid XSL, **but** this namespace only applies to the children of this element.  The `xsi` prefix (that points to this namespace) is also used in a different template in your XSL code, and since the scope of the namespace declaration in `bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement` doesn't extend to this other template, your XSL processor correctly fails to compile your code.

What it would look like after fixing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagos"
            xmlns:bdo_fosfec="http://asocajas.app.com/example">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="registro54"/>
        </bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--TEMPLATE REGISTRO 54-->
    <xsl:template match="registro54">
        <registro54 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro54">
            <registro82 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro82">
                <C512><xsl:value-of select="C512"/></C512>
                <C614><xsl:value-of select="C614"/></C614>
            </registro82>
        </registro54>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: the question link is the next of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045625/design-template-xslt-to-generate-xml thnks

Comment: @Makitodev: Just posted there.  :)  Cheers!