# Design Template XSLT to generate XML

Tags: xml, xslt

i need to generate this xml with all things, namespaces on each node etc

```
<bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagos" 
 xmlns:bdo_fosfec="http://asocajas.app.com/example" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <registro54 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro54">
   <registro82 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro82">
     <C512>39756656</C512>
     <C614>YAXMINNI</C614>
   </registro82>
 </registro54>
 <registro54 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro54">
   <registro82 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro82">
     <C512>79374740</C512>
     <C614>VICTOR</C614>
   </registro82>
 </registro54>
</bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement>
```

And i build a this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagos" xmlns:bdo_fosfec="http://asocajas.app.com/example" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="registro54"/>
   </bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement>
 </xsl:template>
 <!--TEMPLATE REGISTRO 54-->
 <xsl:template match="registro54">
   <registro54 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro54">
        <registro82 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro82">
          <C512><xsl:value-of select="C512"/></C512>
          <C614><xsl:value-of select="C614"/></C614>
        </registro82>
   </registro54>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but when i transform **myxml** with the XSLT the **result xml** is not as expected

**result**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagos" xmlns:bdo_fosfec="http://asocajas.app.com/example" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

**myxml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <bdo_fosfec_x003A_RegistrosPagosElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <registro54>
     <registro82>
      <C512>123456789</C512>
      <C614>Miguel</C614>
     </registro82>
    </registro54>
    <registro54>
     <registro82>
      <C512>1234567890</C512>
      <C614>Jerónimo</C614>
     </registro82>
    </registro54>
  </bdo_fosfec_x003A_RegistrosPagosElement>
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong, I've tried removing the nameSpace xmlns: xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi: type = "bdo_fosfec: RegistersPages" xmlns: bdo_fosfec = "http: //asocajas.hp.com/bdo_fosfec "of the stylesheet but it generates error, I also tried not to use" templates "and the result approaches the desired one but it is not the same that I hope

Thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're getting a bit confused about context, and this is leading to faulty XPath selectors.

#### First problem

You start here:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagos" xmlns:bdo_fosfec="http://asocajas.app.com/example" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="registro54"/>
    </bdo_fosfec:RegistrosPagosElement>
</xsl:template>
```

So you `match`ed on the logical root element.  Within the context of this logical root element, you use `xsl:apply-templates` -- but with `select="registro54"`.  This XPath is looking for any `registro54` elements that are immediate children of the context element.  However, the immediate child of the logical root is the topmost element in the file, in your case, `bdo_fosfec_x003A_RegistrosPagosElement`.  So this `select` statement selects nothing.

We can fix this by changing one of two things.  Either:

1. Change your `xsl:template match` statement to `xsl:template match="/bdo_fosfec_x003A_RegistrosPagosElement"`,
   or
2. Change your `xsl:apply-templates select` statement to `xsl:apply-templates select="bdo_fosfec_x003A_RegistrosPagosElement/registro54"`.

#### Second problem

Even after implementing this first fix, we don't get what we need.  Your second template:

```
<xsl:template match="registro54">
    <registro54 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro54">
        <registro82 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro82">
            <C512><xsl:value-of select="C512"/></C512>
            <C614><xsl:value-of select="C614"/></C614>
        </registro82>
    </registro54>
</xsl:template>
```

So our context is the `registro54` element.  We try to get values using these two statements:

```
            <C512><xsl:value-of select="C512"/></C512>
            <C614><xsl:value-of select="C614"/></C614>
```

These produce nothing, again because the XPaths select nothing.  Within the context of `registro54`, these `select` statements try to find immediate children of `registro54` that are named `C512` or `C614`.

However, if we look at your input XML:

```
<registro54 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro54">
    <registro82 xsi:type="bdo_fosfec:Registro82">
        <C512>39756656</C512>
        <C614>YAXMINNI</C614>
    </registro82>
</registro54>
```

... we see that the `C512` and `C614` elements are children of `registro82` instead.  So to actually get these values, change your `select` statements to:

```
            <C512><xsl:value-of select="registro82/C512"/></C512>
            <C614><xsl:value-of select="registro82/C614"/></C614>
```

#### Conclusion

Remember that `select` with relative XPaths (any XPath expression that doesn't start with `/`, the logical root) will only ever select from the starting point of the context element.

Comment: Your suggested fixes for the first problem won't work because the root element of the input xml isn't in a namespace so your xpaths won't match/select anything.

Comment: you right @DanielHaley, i already edited your answer to fit the first problem and "myxml" of the second problem. Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot and yes you're right, I had several problems in the XSLT file. Haa, also your answer as correct. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielHaley -- Thank you for the sanity check.  I tested it all in OxygenXML using Saxon HE 9.6.0.7, and changing the `select` works just fine -- but between various interruptions, I forgot to mention that the namespace declaration for the `bdo_fosfec:` prefix must be moved before changing the `match`.  I'll edit momentarily.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - The root element of the input (`myxml` in the question) is actually `bdo_fosfec_x003A_RegistrosPagosElement` (notice there's no namespace prefix at all). Sounds like the OP has it figured out though so no big deal. +1

Comment: @Makitodev, apologies for my confusion earlier.  You'd proposed an edit to fix what Daniel just commented about, and I referred to the wrong XML when reviewing your edit -- I mistakenly looked at the desired output, rather than the **myxml** input.  I'll fix my post.